# $_SESSION["danger/success"] em php para mostrar alertas

Tags: php, session, alert

logicaUsuario.php

```
<?php
session_start();
function usuarioEstaLogado(){
    return isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"]);
};
function verificaUsuario(){
    if (!usuarioEstaLogado()){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "Você não tem acesso a essa funcionalidade";
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    };
};
function usuarioLogado(){
    return $_SESSION["usuario_logado"];
};
function logaUsuario($email){
    $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $email;
};
function logOut(){
    session_destroy();
};
```

index.php

```
 <?php 
        include("header.php");
        include("logicaUsuario.php");
        if(isset($_SESSION["success"])): 
    ?>
            <div class="alert-box">
                <p class="alert success"><?= $_SESSION["success"] ;?></p>
            </div>
    <?php
        ;elseif(isset($_SESSION["danger"])):
    ?>
            <div class="alert-box">
                <p class="alert error"><?= $_SESSION["danger"] ;?></p>
            </div>
    <?php
        ;endif;
        unset($_SESSION["success"]);
        unset($_SESSION["danger"]);
    ?>

        <div class="container">



        </div>

    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
include("logicaUsuario.php");
verificaUsuario();
logOut();
$_SESSION["success"] = "Deslogado com sucesso";
header("Location: index.php");
```

Estou tentando fazer com que, quando usuário `deslogue`, apareça uma mensagem dizendo que foi bem sucedido, porém, a mensagem não aparece, fiz com restrição de acesso para `logado/deslogado`, e funcionou, porém não estou conseguindo com `logout`

Comment: No arquivo `logicaUsuario.php` não da `unset` no `success` ?

Comment: Alguém deve estar matando a sessão antes de imprimir.

Comment: Adicionei a lógica de usuário à pergunta.
@ShutUpMagda, tentei passar o session_destroy depois da mensagem, mas ainda assim não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logicaUsuario.php` está matando a sessão em `session_destroy();` porque essa função destrói todos os dados associados com a sessão atual: [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php).

Ao invés de usar `session_destroy();`, especifique quais itens da sessão vc quer destruir e quais quer manter:

```
function logOut(){
    #session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['item0']);
    unset($_SESSION['item1']);
    unset($_SESSION['item0']);
};
```

Ou reiniciar a sessão com `session_start()`:

```
function logOut(){
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
};
```

Deixe setado apenas `$_SESSION["success"]`, o `index.php` já tem uma instrução para destruí-lo após o uso.

Comment: e como eu faria isso ?

Comment: `echo $_SESSION["success"];` e então `unset($_SESSION["success"])`.

Comment: me refiro a especificar quais são destruídos e quais permanecem

Comment: Editei a resposta ;)

Comment: Feito, obrigado :3